# Create a datetime value from separate date time columns

Tags: sql, oracle, timestamp

I have individual columns for year, month, day, hour, minute, second and millisecond. I need to combine them all together into a date timestamp. I am able to make a date value, but can't seem to make a valid time one. I am working in Oracle and I have sample below. I'd like my value to look like the createtime column.

This did the trick:

```
to_timestamp(XT.MONTH1||'-'||XT.DAY1||'-'||XT.YEAR||' '|| xt.hour24||'.'||xt.minute||'.'||xt.second||'.'||xt.milliseconds,'MM-DD-YYYY HH24:MI:SS.FF')
```

[image]

Comment: There is no "time value" in Oracle. Oracle has `date` and `timestamp` data types, as well as `interval`, but not a "time-of-day" data type. In most cases, you don't need that separately anyway - you either need `date` (which always includes time of day, despite its name), or - less often - `interval day to second`.

Comment: what to_date or to_timestamp format are you using in your code?

Comment: append them together in a select, then wrap that with a to_timestamp() call

Comment: i am using the createtime field as an example of how i need the output to look. i have extracted the year,month,hour,minute,second, milliseconds column from somewhere else. i need to combine them all together to become an actual datetime value

Comment: if i concatenate them all together i get not valid month or other issues have been need it to be a hour between 1 and 12

Comment: In your example, the order of columns do not match with your date format. You start with xt.month, but the format starts with `DD` for day.

Comment: thatjeffsmith are you the actual "thatjeffsmith"? i use your blog all the time!

Comment: @hadoo - Yes, he is. Very generous with his time on this site and at OTN, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is quite easy but not pretty. You convert the columns from datatype `NUMBER` to `VARCHAR2` padded with leading zeros, using `fm` to suppress any spaces for `+` or `-`:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(month,'fm00') FROM mytable;
05
```

Next, you glue the converted columns together with the `||` operator to get a single, long, string:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(year,'fm0000')||TO_CHAR(month,'fm00')|| ...
20200519...
```

This long string can now be converted to datatype `DATE`, or, in your case `TIMESTAMP` as you have milliseconds. You need to specify the date format you used, f.i. 'YYYYMMDD...'

```
SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP(TO_CHAR(year,'fm0000')|| ... , 'YYYYMM')
```

A complete example looks like:

```
SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP(
         TO_CHAR(year,'fm0000')||TO_CHAR(month,'fm00')||
         TO_CHAR(day,'fm00')||TO_CHAR(hour24,'fm00')||
         TO_CHAR(minute,'fm00')||TO_CHAR(second,'fm00')||
         TO_CHAR(ms,'fm000')
         , 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISSFF3')
  FROM (-- your table, as a mockup, I'll use DUAL
        SELECT 2020 as year, 5 as month, 19 as day, 
               13 as hour24, 7 as minute, 10 as second, 
               300 as ms 
          FROM DUAL);

2020-05-19 13:07:10,300000000
```

EDIT:

The fill mode modifier `fm` supresses a leading space for positive numbers (to make room for the `-` sign for negative numbers). All parts of a date are positive, so you get a lot of spaces in your string.

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(x,'99'), TO_CHAR(x,'fm99')
  FROM (SELECT -10 as x FROM DUAL UNION ALL SELECT 10 FROM DUAL);
| 10|10|
|-10|-10|
```

The documentation is a bit hidden under [Format Model Modifiers](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Format-Models.html#GUID-7FF68D9E-C7E2-4CA1-9DDB-5CC7169EEEEA).

Come to think of it, you might as well keep the spaces and adjust your format model:

```
SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP(
         TO_CHAR(year,'0000')||TO_CHAR(month,'00')||
         TO_CHAR(day,'00')||TO_CHAR(hour24,'00')||
         TO_CHAR(minute,'00')||TO_CHAR(second,'00')||
         TO_CHAR(ms,'000')
         ,' YYYY MM DD HH24 MI SS FF3')
  FROm (SELECT 2020 as year, 5 as month, 19 as day, 
                 13 as hour24, 7 as minute, 10 as second, 
                300 as ms FROM DUAL);
```

Comment: this worked exactly what i needed. can i ask what the 'fm' aspect is doing, i do not understand that. thank you